# Parse Json key/values of a key's value using JObject using PHP

Tags: php, json

Please can any help me on this, to remove all keys that have values of N/A, -, or empty strings. If one of the values appear in an array then remove that single item from the array

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Robert",
    "middle": "",
    "last": "Smith"
  },
  "age": 25,
  "DOB": "-",
  "hobbies": [
    "running",
    "coding",
    "-"
  ],
  "education": {
    "highschool": "N/A",
    "college": "Yale"
  }
}
```

Expecting result would be:
{
"name": {
"first": "Robert",
"last": "Smith"
},
"age": 25,
"hobbies": [
"running",
"coding"
],
"education": {
"highschool": "N/A",
"college": "Yale"
}
}

Comment: Use a recursive function that iterates through the properties and removes any property with one of those values.

Comment: Hi @Barmar thanks for the comment. Can you be able to code that for me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following logic to remove elements from your source data:

The recursive function `cleanUp()` cycles through the data and removes all the entries with values that are set in array `$remove`

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$remove = ['N/A', '-','',];
cleanUp($arr, $remove);

function cleanUp(array &$arr, array $remove = [])
{
    foreach($arr as $key => &$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            cleanUp($value, $remove);
        } else {
            if(in_array($value, $remove)) unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/JCW0V)

Comment: glad I could help!